# Cluster elements that appear in the same lists

Tags: python, clustering, similarity, distance

Suppose I have a multitude of sets with (unordered) combinations of elements and I want to determine **which elements *tend* to appear together**.

#### For example

Given the following sets:

```
{a,e,g}
{a,e,h}
{a,e,i}
{b,f,j}
{b,f,k}
{b,f,l}
{d,c,m}
{d,c,n}
{d,c,o}
```

Element-pairs where both elements tend to occur in the same sets will have lower distance:

```
# Low-distance pairs:
{a,e}, {b,f}, {d,c}

# Medium-distance pairs
{a,g}, {b,j}, {d,m}, ...

# High-distance pairs:
{g,h}, {j,n}, {b,f}, ...
```

#### Currently

I'm implementing [DBSCAN with a custom distance metric](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#how-do-i-deal-with-string-data-or-trees-graphs). I use the following distance metric between two elements:

```
d(a,b) = 1 - numsets(a, b) / (numsets(a,!b) + numsets(b,!a))
```

Where `d(a,b)` denote the distance between elements `a` and `b`. While `numsets` denotes how many sets fulfill some conditions:

- `numsets(a, b)` - the number of sets that contain `a` and `b`
- `numsets(a,!b)` - the number of sets that contain `a` but not `b`

This solution should achieve the goal however it's not a pretty solution and I couldn't find this problem on SE. In terms of solving the problem, **is there a more sensible distance metric?** In terms of implementation, **is there a nicer way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a data mining problem, specifically [affinity analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_analysis).

One common method to solve it is the [Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your metric might suffer division by zero, or have negative values. It's pretty close to [Jaccard distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index), so maybe consider that.  See also   http://curtis.ml.cmu.edu/w/courses/index.php/Co-occurrence_metrics

You might also have success with a graph clustering approach, see for a start
http://www.ecography.org/blog/clustering-or-network-methods-comparing-different-methods-bioregionalisation

Answer (score -1):

**Levenshtein distance** (and its cousing Jaro, Hemming etc...)

Levenshtein distance for measuring the difference between two sequences between two words is the minimum number of single-character edits (insertions, deletions or substitutions) required to change one word (your case one set of characters) into the other.

There are a couple implementations, for example [here](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/metrics/distance.html), its the "edit_distance" function.

Comment: Given that the sets of combinations are unordered, Levenstein is not a good metric.

Comment: True, but you can sort them (if thats possible given the task-in the example yes)

Comment: I've tried to mull it over. Levenstein measures distance between sequences. I need the distance between elements.